# Jquery loop through li one by one

Tags: jquery, html, css, loops

I have the following code which displays an li item one by one.

```
var show = 1;
var current = show - 1;
var length = 9;

var gallery = $('.quotescroll');



var galleryItems = gallery.children('li');
length = galleryItems.length;


setInterval(function(){
    current = (current+1)%60;

    galleryItems.eq(current).slideDown();
    galleryItems.eq(current - show).slideUp();
}, 10000);
```

The only trouble i have is that I now need it to loop throught the unordered list continuously. How would i acheive this?

***EDIT***

I found this code which does exactly what i need, however it doesn't have the nice slide animation.

```
 setInterval(function() {
     var firstLi = $('.quotescroll li').first().detach();
    $('.quotescroll').append($(firstLi));
 }, 5000);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "continuously"?

Comment: I think, he want's to repeat what he is doing in `setInterval` once reached at the last li.

Comment: @tymeJV I'd guess that by "continuously" he means that when it reaches the end he wants it to go back to the beginning and iterate through them again. Perhaps "cycle" would be a better word than "loop". Hopefully Sean will either confirm this or clarify what they actually meant.

Comment: sorry, yes this is what i meant.

Comment: @SeanLang Check my answer below. That suppose to solve your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `quotescroll` is your list class:

```
$('.quotescroll li').each(function() {
    //this now refers to each li
    //do stuff to each
});
```

Comment: sorry, im new to this. How would i display each li one by one using this?

Answer (score 2):

```
$( ".quotescroll li" ).each(function( index ) {
      console.log( index + ": " + $(this).text() );
});
```

should do it

Details can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: By targeting li elements you might target other li's in his code that he don't want them to be targeted. You need to be more specific: $(.quotescroll li) or $(gallery, 'li').

Comment: @Lior Yes, that was meant as more of a generic `selector` but I imagine some explicitness would be in order here.

Comment: Great! it will only serve him

Answer (score 2):

> Iterate Over a jQuery Object

For looping through your **li**'s selectors, good practice is to use the **each()** function which iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element.

Per your example:

```
$(gallery, 'li').each(function() {
    //Your code goes here
    //$(this) will target the current li being iterated
});
```

Its syntax is: `$(selector).each(function(index, Element))`

You can also check the jQuery API Documentation **[here](http://api.jquery.com/each/)**